# Not enough permissions to access: GET /me/

Tags: laravel-5, linkedin-api

I am getting the access token, but not able to proceed further with the API calls.
I am getting the Not enough permission to access those API, I tried both APIs of v1 and v2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your access is liteprofile and not basicprofile